# Why doesn't Google Webmaster Tools show more than one query to my popular site?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search

I am looking at the webmaster tools site dashboard for a prominent website I have. The account is linked with analytics. I'm confused as to why I only have item listed under the queries. For the past month there have been 257,000 impressions and 26,500 clicks on my homepage. The only query that is listed though is the name of the business that the site is for.

This doesn't make any sense to me because the site is indexed properly and there are plenty of other searches pertaining to this business that I am absolutely sure are showing up in the SERPs. Why is webmaster tools only showing me one query?

Comment: How long has the Webmaster Tools account existed for this site? I have noticed that it can take 1-2 full months before the data begins to reflect reality.

Comment: @closetnoc That seems like an incredibly long time. The account has been set up for two days now. I set up an account for another domain just YESTERDAY and it already has 32 queries listed. The traffic on that site is minimal, ~100 a month. I have read about days or weeks even, but you are the first one to tell me months.

Comment: It is generally at least 30 days and sometimes longer before all of the metrics and information makes sense. Not sure why. Given the fact that the data is free and the amount of data Google has to track to do this, I fully understand the complexity and difficulty.

Comment: Should also be noted users that are logged in to Google will not be displayed under any search term as this was changed donkeys ago because of privacy, also query data should be considered sample data, as its very slow, incomplete and so on.

Comment: Google Webmaster Tools does show aggregate query counts even for users that search while logged into Google.   The data comes internally from Google and Webmaster Tools doesn't have to rely on it being present in the referrer.

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the right version of the site (http/https/www/non-www/"m."). It needs to be the version that's indexed so that it can show that data.

Comment: Buddy, i think you are in rush, because it takes time to see the results. You must be new and want result soon, if not the case then check your robots.txt.

Comment: When was the site added to Webmaster tools? If it was recently it takes some time to index all the search terms.

Answer (score 1):

> When you add your site to Search Console, it may take some time before diagnostic and other data is available. This is normal; it can take some time for Search Console to gather and process data for your site. In general, if you see a "No data yet" message, check back later. Once Google starts crawling your site more often, you'll notice that Search Console will begin to show more detailed data, and that this data is updated more often.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2571221?hl=en

As other people said, you need to wait.

For troubleshooting:

- Make sure you put the correct www or non www version of your website, as the link above suggests
- Follow the official guide for checking indexing https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34444?hl=en
- There's a similar issue for http and https website. They're considered different websites. For more info look here: [Google Webmaster Tools search analytics Queries volume drop](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81653/google-webmaster-tools-search-analytics-queries-volume-drop/81754#81754)

> In order to see the index count for your secure site, you will need to add it to Search Console (e.g. https://www.example.com) and then select it from the Site Selector.