# Google Webmaster Tools showing no clicks on any queries

Tags: seo, google-search-console, clicks

As you will see from the screenshot attached there is a clear discrepancy between the number of impressions and the lack thereof clicks, thus no CTR data.

I know WMT don’t give you the full amount of data but this is giving me zero clicks for brand related terms.

[image: WMT Screen grab]

I’ve just started with this company so I don’t know if it was always like this.

Comment: There may be something wrong with the GWT keywords report right now.   This was asked yesterday: [Why doesn't Google Webmaster Tools show more than one query to my popular site?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77087/why-doesnt-google-webmaster-tools-show-more-than-one-query-to-my-popular-site)

Comment: Should note that Clicks are not shown as queries if the users are logged into Google.

Comment: This list by default is sorted by Impressions. You can sort by Clicks where you should see something- I assume. It is very normal to have a significant number of impressions and no clicks. This is more exaggerated on lower volume sites where SERP performance is limited.

Comment: Another thought: Im sure you know this, but make sure you are looking at the right site with the right protocol. For example, if you recently switched to full SSL mode and you are looking at the HTTP proto version in GWT, the stats would show a drop-off to nothing. Meanwhile the HTTPS proto version in GWT would be gaining stats (even if you didnt define or verify it yet).

Comment: In addition to the protocol, make sure you're looking at the right version of the site (www/non-www/"m.").

Comment: Thanks John, I have resolved the issue somewhat. There was another version (https) of the site submitted which is tracking clicks correctly. This might explain why this version (www) was not tracking properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can troubleshoot this by comparing GWT report with your **Audience -> All Traffic -> Channels** report. If your organic traffic didn't change dramatically during the time in questions then its a GWT issue.

Comment: Thanks guys for your response. Its definitely GMT issues as there is no sudden drop off in organic traffic. The traffic is there its just not computing correctly. I'll contact WMT so.