# Google Webmaster Tools search analytics Queries volume drop

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

I see a massive drop in my Google Webmaster Tools Search Analytics, but in my Google Analytics I see no drop, even an increase in traffic.

The only recent changes I made is that I now redirect http requests to https.
Other than that there's really nothing changed. Could that be it?

What is going on?

[image]
[image]

Comment: As it is, users could only guess. Please add as many details as you can (e.g., such as changes to your site, tracking code you're using, etc...) to help make this question more answerable and applicable to others in the future.

Comment: I would like to see more so that you can get a good answer or some idea as to what is going on. As it sits, there is nothing to really grasp.

Comment: So, from webmaster tools you see a drop in organic search, but in google analytics you see an increase of organic traffic? Show us your "Impressions" and "Position" trend.

Comment: @lucgenti Yes. I've updated my post with a new image.

Comment: You get fewer clicks because you get also fewer impressions. Are you sure you see an increase of traffic through organic search? Your average position is the same (the low peaks could be google just testing serp ranking). How much time has been going on this trend? Wide the date range. Show us also your CTRs.

Comment: Look also at the total pages, not just the queries. See if you are experiencing de-indexing. And also devices, maybe there's something that blocks mobile.

Comment: @lucgenti thanks again this is really helping me in analyzing! I've added more data, but still don't see anything that could explain the drop in clicks.

Comment: I need a confirmation that you didn't give me: is your organic search increasing in google analytics? Also I removed the 3rd screenshot (I intended not mobile usability report, but filtering by mobile device). No need to add more. After you answer me, I think we should move the discussion to chat as the system is suggesting.

Comment: @lucgenti Ah, sorry. And organic search has not been increasing heavily, just very very steadily over the last few months but perhaps more importantly no heavy dips at all.

Comment: When did you migrate from HTTP to HTTPS? Have you added https version to GWT? Are you doing proper canonicalization? Look here https://www.seroundtable.com/search-queries-drop-google-18093.html

Answer (score 2):

After some comments, I think it's an issue regarding migration from HTTP to HTTPS.

You need to add your https version website through Webmaster Tools.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2642366#update

> For example, suppose you have a site with 10 URLs that people can view without signing in, and 100 URLs that people can only see once they sign into your site.  If you have added only one version of your site to Search Console (e.g. http://www.example.com), you would see Index status totals only for the non-secure portion of your site, which would be a much lower number than for all URLs on your site.
>   Therefore, in order to see the index count for your secure site, you will need to add it to Search Console (e.g. https://www.example.com) and then select it from the Site Selector.